# ocamlopt and ocamlbuild give an Unbound module error despite ocamlfind seeing the required module

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, mirage

I'm attempting to build the xencat tool from [this project](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-vchan/tree/master/cli). When I try to use `ocamlopt` to build it, I get

```
$ ocamlopt -o xencat xencat.ml 
File "xencat.ml", line 1, characters 5-13:
Error: Unbound module Cmdliner
```

Following guidance [here](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/compiling_ocaml_projects.html), I verified that cmdliner was installed and that it was visible to `ocamlfind`, and then tried again:

Here's what `ocamlfind list` shows:

```
$ ocamlfind list
bigarray            (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
bytes               (version: [distributed with OCaml 4.02 or above])
...
cmdliner            (version: 0.9.8)
...
```

No luck:

```
$ ocamlfind ocamlopt -o xencat xencat.ml
File "xencat.ml", line 1, characters 5-13:
Error: Unbound module Cmdliner
```

Following this page, I tried ocamlbuild:

```
$ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind xencat.byte
+ ocamlfind ocamlc -c -o xencat.cmo xencat.ml
File "xencat.ml", line 1, characters 5-13:
Error: Unbound module Cmdliner
Command exited with code 2.
```

Clearly I'm missing something, but being new to Ocaml, I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Try `ocamlfind ocamlopt -package cmdliner -o xencat xencat.ml`.

Comment: Ideally, you should use opam to install it. This package has dozens of dependencies, that should be satisfied before you can build this file. So, at first you need install them, presumably using opam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -package cmdliner xencat.byte`

?

Comment: A little progress! Now I'm getting a new Unbound module error, but I think it's telling me I need to build the whole project, not just this particular file. Can you explain why adding the `-package` argument was necessary? I expected ocamlbuild to find the package by itself.

Comment: None of the OCaml tools I know of will try to infer which ocamlfind packages you are using (there is not in general a well-defined mapping from OCaml module names, which the compilation and build tools see, to ocamlfind packages). You have to pass them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

To build this project use the following command at the root of the project:

```
./configure
make build
```

You will find a `xencat.native` file in the root folder.

You can also use `opam` to build it, as `opam` will handle all dependencies to you. Just go to the root of the project and say:

```
opam pin add vchan .
```

and answer yes to whatever opam asks to do.

Comment: Tried your first suggestion, I get 

 `make build
W: Cannot find source file matching module 'vchan' in library vchan
Finished, 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
Finished, 40 targets (39 cached) in 00:00:00.`

Comment: I ended up doing `oasis setup-clean`, `make clean`, `./configure --xenctrl=true` and `make`. The binary was created.